# MySql: How to call a stored procedure before declare statements

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I need call sp before declaring a cursor. The sp fills a table and then the cursor loop in this tables rows. But workbench does not allow call sp or anything else before `declare` statements.

```
create definer=`root`@`%` procedure `usp_tesst`()
begin
declare ordid int;
declare packid int;
declare cstmid int;
declare deltimespanid int;
declare dstrcid int;
declare pcstatus tinyint(1);
declare deliverytime datetime;

declare maxdate datetime;
declare temppackcount int default(0);

    call usp_createtemppackages;

-- it says there is a syntax error in here

    declare crs cursor for 
                select  * from temppackages....
```

How should I call this sp ?

Comment: i know this is old but I am having the same problem. Seems like we cant programmer before declaring. How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE statements must be first in Stored Procedures.

Consider either - 1) calling usp_createtemppackages before calling usp_tesst 2) integrating usp_createtemppackages functionality into usp_tesst 3) Removing the cursor and iterating the table some other way (which may give a performance increase too as cursors are a bit slow).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you need as follows:

```sql
...
declare maxdate datetime;
declare temppackcount int default(0);

/*call usp_createtemppackages;*/

-- it says there is a syntax error in here
    declare crs cursor for 
                select  * from temppackages....

call usp_createtemppackages;
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/976046/1)</kbd>